# Increasing the smoothness of the accuracy curve in image classification

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, cross-validation, image-recognition, tf.keras

I have developed a Convolutional Neural Network using TILDA image dataset which gives over 90% of accuracy with the following model. I used 4 batches and 100 epochs to the model.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input((30,30,1)),
    layers.Conv2D(8,2,padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(16,2,padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(32,2,padding='same', activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(5, activation = "softmax"),
])
```

Using the above model I could plot the following graphs for the training and validation accuracy.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions to increase the smoothness of these curves? What can be the possible reasons for getting such curves? I appreciate your recommendations to improve this model.

Answer (score 0):

The following may help in getting a smoother curve:

1. NEVER use dropout before the final layer. `MaxPool + Dropout` in your model discards 87.5% of the data flowing into the final layer. Avoid pooling as well, unless you need global or adaptive pooling to get a fixed shape output. If you must pool, you need a much larger number of kernels to compensate for the loss in information.
2. Use a lower learning rate. From what the training curve tells, the model is directed to a minima, but with several bumps.
3. Are you using SGD without momentum? If yes, introduce, momentum. Also consider adaptive optimizers with inbuilt momentum, like Adam.
4. Why the `sigmoid` in between? Sigmoid reduces the gradient magnitude and makes learning slower.
5. If you only care about the curve and are not restricted by number of parameters, consider adding a few more layers and/or channels.